# how to do string operation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 11, None],
                   'b': ['apple;', None, 'orange;'],
                   'c': ['red', 'blue', 'green']})
```

I'm trying to strip the ';' of those strings. I tried

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(lambda x: x.strip(';'))
```

I got error message:

```
AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'", 'occurred at   index b')
```

Seems like the None gave me some trouble. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some of the values are `None`, and you can't `Non.strip()`.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
         b      c
0   apple;    red
1     None   blue
2  orange;  green
```

What you can do is `strip` only if the object is not None, otherwise just return the object:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(lambda x: x.strip(';') if x else x)
        b      c
0   apple    red
1    None   blue
2  orange  green
```

Comment: The problem with `lambda x: x.strip(';') if x else x` is that you will have attribute errors with other objects that are falsey in the Python sense and also lack a `.strip` method. You can do `lambda x: x.strip(';') if hasattr(x, 'strip') else x` if you want to do it by testing first.

Comment: @dawg, correct. since the data in the example includes only strings the `if x` was enough. Another option is to check `if type(x) == str`, to make sure the `strip` will be only on strings (and not on other objects that might have the strip function, which we are not sure will return the expected result).

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dekel  just did. just knew I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try` and `except` in this case.

```
>>> def am(o):
...    try:
...       return o.strip(';')
...    except AttributeError:
...       return o
```

Then `applymap` as you have tried:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(am)
        b      c
0   apple    red
1    None   blue
2  orange  green
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Series `str` attribute and `apply` instead of `applymap`:

```
In [17]: df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(lambda S:S.str.strip(';'))
Out[17]: 
        b      c
0   apple    red
1    None   blue
2  orange  green

In [18]:
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to iterate through all the columns that are `dtype` object and use the Series function `strip` that handles NaN values:

```
for col in df.columns[df.dtypes == object]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip(";")
```